# Generate a Key and save it to Model Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

> models.py

```
from django.db import models

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()

class = SecretKey(models.Model):
   key = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique = True)
   owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

> views.py

```
from .serializers import UserProfileSerializer, KeySerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import UserProfile, SecretKey
from rest_framework import viewsets

class ProfileAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()

class GenerateSecretKeyAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = KeySerializer
    queryset = SecretKey.objects.all()
```

> serializers.py

```
class KeySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = SecretKey
    fields = ('key','owner')
```

> urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import ProfileAPIView, GenerateSecretKeyAPIView

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register('stud',StudentProfileAPIView,base_name='stud-prof-api-view'),
router.register('key',GenerateSecretKeyAPIView,base_name='key-gen-api-view'),
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

This is the short description of my api. Now when I call a `POST` request from the front end, which contains a number(n), and the owner's id., I want to create a random number of length n, and save the key into the `key` field and the owner id into the `owner` field of of the `SecretKey` Model

Please Help
Thanks in  Advance

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this :

```
class = SecretKey(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique = True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def generate_key(self):
        key = ''.join(random.choice('0123456789') for x in range(8))

        if SecretKey.objects.filter(key=key).exists():
            return self.generate_key()

        return key

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.key:
            self.key = self.generate_key()

        return super(SecretKey, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Actually when I try the a `POST` request from the frontend, It shows an Error `POST /stud/k/ HTTP/1.1" 400 35` in the terminal of Django server

Comment: my front end request is like `{ "owner" : "1" }` as we are not dealing with **n** in your code

Comment: I think the problem is we are not specifying how to deal with the `POST` request

Comment: try making key `required=False` in serializer

Comment: actually when we call this save() function it's trying to save some data to a field having some pk or id, but what I want is I need to create or generate a new model row when I get this post request, the only problem I'm facing here is one of the tuple is should be customised and stored before creating. which means when a post request is called, I need to generate a new row, with a key(which has to be generated before creating the row) and the owner id value which is passing through the request